# Determining the coordinates of a point in a distorted cube

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Is it possible to express the coordinates of a point in a distorted cube? That is, given a distorted cube in 3D space with 8 points (the coordinates of which are not necessarily on the regular positions you'd expect them to be for a non-distorted cube), and a point within that cube, finding a universal way of expressing its position. And if this is possible, is there some established method for determining this alternative expression, so as to transfer it to a differently distorted cube?

The tetrahedron-equivalent of this would be to use a barycentric coordinate system, but that is for 4-point simplexes.

Comment: How distorted is it? For example are the faces planar?

Comment: Not necessarily, no. The distortion should be arbitrary, excluding of course any twists/switches (the contained volume should be intact and positive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is called trilinear interpolation: linear interpolation in three variables.

Let the vertices be called $\vec{p}_{000}$, $\vec{p}_{001}$, $\vec{p}_{010}$, $\vec{p}_{011}$, $\vec{p}_{100}$, $\vec{p}_{101}$, $\vec{p}_{110}$, and $\vec{p}_{111}$.

Let $u$ axis be between $\vec{p}_{0 v w}$ and $\vec{p}_{1 v w}$, $v$ axis be between $\vec{p}_{u 0 w}$ and $\vec{p}_{u 1 w}$, and $w$ axis between $\vec{p}_{u v 0}$ and $\vec{p}_{u v 1}$, for $u, v, w \in 0, 1$.

Then, $(u, v, w)$ is within the cuboid if and only if $0 \le u, v, w \le 1$, and corresponds to point $\vec{p}$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\vec{p} & = ((\vec{p}_{111} u + \vec{p}_{011} (1 - u)) v + (\vec{p}_{101} u + \vec{p}_{001} (1 - u)) (1 - v)) w \\
~ & + ((\vec{p}_{110} u + \vec{p}_{010} (1 - u)) v + (\vec{p}_{100} u + \vec{p}_{000} (1 - u)) (1 - v)) (1 - w) \\
\end{aligned}$$

This is trilinear interpolation, because if we use $L(p_0, p_1, x)$ to denote linear interpolation between $p_0$ and $p_1$,
$$L(p_0, p_1, x) = (1 - x)p_0 + x p_1 = p_0 + x (p_1 - p_0)$$
then
$$\begin{aligned}
\vec{p} & = L(L(L(\vec{p}_{000}, \vec{p}_{100}, u), L(\vec{p}_{010}, \vec{p}_{110}, u), v), L(L(\vec{p}_{001}, \vec{p}_{101}, u), L(\vec{p}_{011}, \vec{p}_{111}, u), v), w) \\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I had considered this, but I'm not sure whether this will work on convex-deformed cubes (e.g. where one point is moved inwards, beyond the original center of the cube, to have an arrow-point-like structure). And, I am even more unsure how you then transfer this to a differently transformed cube. Because while I can write the point like this, how do I use this as a set of coordinate for a different cube?

Comment: @gandreadis: It works for any shape of cuboid, but the edges may curves instead of straight lines.  If the cuboid is not degenerate, the transform is invertible: given $\vec{p}$ and the cuboid vertices, you can solve for $u$, $v$, and $w$.  Remember, in 3D, it is actually a set of three equations, one for each Cartesian coordinate.

Comment: Thanks! That's great :)